# Collation type For Portuguese

Tags: php, collation

i want to insert the “ã”, “é”, “ó”, “ç”( Dvorak International) like text in Portuguese-Brazil language.
i set the collation type in database is:
 **utf8_general_ci**
but its not working.i am trying to paste it here ,but here it is showing fine.but in database it is not showing in proper way.

So ,please tell me which collation is right for Portuguese.

My HTML Page character encoding is:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=pt-BR" />
```

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: `pt-BR` is not an *encoding*.

Comment: if i am not settling pt-BR than the words comes like this ?ass?d

Comment: Please read the above linked article. You need to declare what *encoding* your content is in, which depends on how you get it from the database. "pt-BR" is a *locale*, i.e. a description of a *language* (Brazilian Portuguese), an *encoding* is something else and has nothing to do with the *language* (e.g. UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, etc).

Comment: "set names utf8" - "SET NAMES indicates what character set the client will use to send SQL statements to the server."

Comment: okay so i fixed the encoding utf-8 in my file & my database also,but still shows wrong charecter,but one thing is there that one of my filed having Text Type is coverted correctly and stored fien but the others which are in varchar is given the probelm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-8 should work fine for Portuguese language.

Try this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

edit:

Then 2 things might be happening:

1. the encoding in the database is wrong for the strings inside it
2. The file encoded wrongly. (is encoded in something else besides UTF-8).

Comment: no it is not working if i put this as Utf-8 than the Portuguese word shown like ????.

Comment: i am using utf8_general_ci collation in database.

Comment: but Kaern if i am not using pt-BR in My HTML code than the Portuguese words are not showing properly.,you can try charter set UTF8 for Portuguese,it is not working.

Comment: What's she's saying is that there might be a missmatch between your database encondig and the data being passed to the database

Answer (score 3):

As a brazilian programmer, I've faced this situation several times. Problem is, according to my experience, that simply encoding the page with the proper charset (in case of Brazilian Portuguese that is ISO-8859-1), won't fix the problem.

Both database and the page must be encoded accordingly. To the best of my knowledge, in the HTML portion of the problem the meta tag should be as follows:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

Note: as Tivie noted on another answer, it is not enough to set the charset only via meta tag. The encoding of the file (example.htm) must also be set to Ansi rather than Unicode or UTF-8, otherwise accented characters (such as á ô í ç) will be displayed incorrectly.

Regarding the database, in order to retrieve info and display correctly, you must also set the correct charset and collation, as below (for MySQL):

Character Set: latin1 -- cp1252 West European

Collation: latin1_swedish_ci (despite the 'swedish', it is the one that works best with brazilian portuguese.)

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that the encoding of your files is missmatched with your meta tag, since passing an invalid charset seems to show the characters correctly.

Example:

You have a index.html

If you add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` in index.html, then the file encoding should be UTF-8 and not something else.

You can find the encoding of your files using notepad++ on windows. If you're using a MAC, your files are probably encoded in MacRoman.

Check this link, it explains how to check the file encoding using Notepad++: http://www.abdullahyahya.com/2011/09/22/find-out-a-files-encoding-on-windows/

Comment: okay so i fixed the encoding utf-8 in my file & my database also,but still shows wrong charecter,but one thing is there that one of my filed having Text Type is coverted correctly and stored fien but the others which are in varchar is given the probelm.

Comment: You should double-check the encoding being sent from the webserver. .htaccess can override everything you are doing in your webpage silently and you will never know.

http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-headers-charset.en.php